# how to capture a 3d depth image with blaster senz3d on openCV

Tags: python, opencv, 3d

I have the following python code that allows me to take video/image from any camera attached to the computer, however when I try to get images from the 3d detph sensor, I get the right size of image (VGA size) but all pixels have the same value. 
I know the 3D camera works because I use it in other programs.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read();
    imgDepth = frame.depth();
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(gray);
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('imgDepth',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What's the value of the pixels in the BGR frame ?

Comment: the size of image is (480, 640, 3)

each pixel contains: [  0 136   0]

Answer (score 0):

The way to access the depth camera is different
see example: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/python/examples/opencv_viewer_example.py

```
## License: Apache 2.0. See LICENSE file in root directory.
## Copyright(c) 2015-2017 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

###############################################
##      Open CV and Numpy integration        ##
###############################################

import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

# Start streaming
pipeline.start(config)

try:
    while True:

        # Wait for a coherent pair of frames: depth and color
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
        color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
        if not depth_frame or not color_frame:
            continue

        # Convert images to numpy arrays
        depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

        # Apply colormap on depth image (image must be converted to 8-bit per pixel first)
        depth_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.03), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

        # Stack both images horizontally
        images = np.hstack((color_image, depth_colormap))

        # Show images
        cv2.namedWindow('RealSense', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        cv2.imshow('RealSense', images)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

finally:

    # Stop streaming
    pipeline.stop()
```